# SwiftUI View doesn't update when API fetches new data?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Before I say anything else, I'm actually a beginner level in Swift and SwiftUI but I'm always trying to accomplish things that don't meet my level of knowledge. I've had an idea of bringing bus information to live activities. I've managed to find an api of my local transportation and created a SwiftUI list view for the next bus in a specific bus station.

There's actually a tutorial on youtube that shows how to fetch the data (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CimY_Sr3gWw&t=221) and he uses @Published var bus: [BusAPI] = [] to let the view know that when the API data changes then it has to refresh.

I'm fetching the API data this way.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct BusAPI: Hashable, Codable {
    let route_code: String
    let veh_code: String
    let btime2: String
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var bus: [BusAPI] = [] 
    func fetch() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://telematics.oasa.gr/api/?act=getStopArrivals&p1=060475") else {
            return
        }
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] data, _, error in
            
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                return
            }
            //Convert to JSON
            do {
                let bus = try JSONDecoder().decode([BusAPI].self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.bus = bus
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

The View looks like this:

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  BusDemoAPI
//


import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(viewModel.bus, id: \.self) { bus in
                
                    HStack {
                        Text("N. Ελβετία - Άνω Πατήσια")
                        Spacer()
                        Text("\(bus.btime2)'")
                            
                    }.padding(3)
                    
                }
            }.navigationTitle("Στάση ΟΠΑ")
            .onAppear {
                viewModel.fetch()
            }
            
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

My actual question is why doesnt the view refreshes when the data changes? It's always stuck on the time that it first fetched the data.

I've tried to find a solution on google but nothing actually helped.

Comment: "My actual question is why doesn't the view refresh when the data changes? It's always stuck on the time that it first fetched the data." 
This implies your view was successfully updated initially via the onAppear modifier but didn't after.  Note the onAppear modifier isn't triggered if you background and foreground your app on the same view. You can instead set a timer in your view model on init to repeatedly call the fetch method or add a button to test that the fetch method updates the UI. Also, note the previous answer regarding the duplicate bus property and var isn't correct

Comment: Your `viewModel` is observed by the view, when the data inside the app changes, the UI will refresh.
It does not `observe` the data changes on the server.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question `My actual question is why doesnt the view refreshes when the data changes?`
is because your code does not
update by itself when the data on the server is updated. You need to fetch the `new` data yourself when
you decide to do so.

One simple way to do this, is to add a `.refreshable` modifier to your `List`, so that when
the user do a
**pull-to-refresh gesture** (quick swipe down of the list), the list contents is re-fetched and thus updated with the latest bus info.

```
 List {...}
   .refreshable {
      viewModel.fetch()
   }
```

Note, you are using an insecure `http` connection, Apple requires to use `https`.